# How to call AIR API in Java?

Tags: java, air

I knew AIR2 provide NativeProcess for AIR developers easily to invoke C++/Java application. But is there any easy way for Java developer to trigger AIR application or even invoke the API in AIR lib?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it looks like it is what you are looking for http://doit.juii.net/uncategorized/1178